# facebook like button is not working is not working with Cyrillic domain

Tags: facebook, dns, facebook-like

Facebook like button is not working with Cyrillic domains.  I've tried diffrent methods, but I still cannot see it. 
What can I do to resolve it.

Comment: `I've tried`- [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Remarks: I've tried to convert to Ascii - no result. But I found that it works with non-cyrilic top-level domain. My top-level domain - ".рф" (cyrilic).

Answer (score 0):

did you try punnycode (fore reference see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)? you might want to check punycode converter on http://mct.verisign-grs.com/ (first google result I had)

you could try using punnycode converter from Cyrillic IDN (internationalized domain name) from Unicode to Ascii (format readable by browsers), so it would look like:

Unicode пример.ru

ASCII xn--e1afmkfd.ru

Im not sure if this will help, but try to use this Ascii version of your Cyrillic url in facebook code.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to convert it to Ascii - no result. But I found that it work with non-cyrilic top-level domain. But I have top-level domain - ".рф".

Comment: did you also try to convert .рф to Ascii?

пример.рф
xn--e1afmkfd.xn--p1ai

Comment: Yes. I've tried: - пример.рф (it does not work) and пример.ru (it works). It does not matter convert or not.